# How to make a background from 3 parts on website

Tags: html, css

So i want to make a background for a page that has an image on the right a difrent image on the left and a repeated strip of black in the middle. how can i make this. So that if a user has a bigger monitor image on the right will stay on the right and image on the left will stay on the left but in the center the black will repeat as many times as needed

Comment: nothing yet im asking to see wich way would be better so that i wouldn't have to spend alot of time on it

Comment: Like nearly everything with web design and development, there isn't just one magical 'better way'.

Comment: [lots of good snippets and examples here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

This might not be possible by body background image, but you can use 2 fixed div for side backgrounds and one body background for center. Look at this link http://jsfiddle.net/k2FPz/1/